# как сверстать вот эту секцию на гридах

Tags: html, css, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<section class="catalog-car">
    <div class="catalog-car__content">
        <img src="img/firstcar.jpg" alt="" class="catalog-car__img">
        <img src="img/secondcar.jpg" alt="" class="catalog-car__img">
        <img src="img/lastcar.jpg" alt="" class="catalog-car__img">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2vw;
  }
#grid > div {
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding: .5em;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
}

#grid > div:first-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

У меня нет Ваших картинок, но можете посмотреть на саму логику.